# Display table from entities in symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I need just to display the first 24 lines of records in entities; so that in the second column (lun) it shows first 24 records and in the third one (mardi) it shows next 24 records and so on

```
<table width="80%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr style=" width:100%;">
            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>lun</th>
            <th>mardi</th>
            <th>mercredi</th>
            <th>jeudi</th>
            <th>vendredi</th>
            <th>Samedi</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for entity in entities %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue
Here is the code in my controller:

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('PublishDemandsBundle:Appointement')->findBy(array('therapist'=>$user));
```

Comment: Your question is nearly incomprehensible. We don't know anything about your code. You should explain it better.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What kind of a thing is 'entity'? What do you mean by "lines from entities"? Is your entity related to another 'line' entity and you need to display related lines in the relevant columns?

Comment: i need to display the  first  24 id in my tabledatabase in colone lundi and the 24 to 48 id from my database tables in mardi and i edit my question.Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood what you want, but try this:

```
<table width="80%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr style=" width:100%;">
            <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>lun</th>
            <th>mardi</th>
            <th>mercredi</th>
            <th>jeudi</th>
            <th>vendredi</th>
            <th>Samedi</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for i in 0..23) %}
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><a href="">{{ entities[i].id }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="">{{ entities[i+24].id }}</a></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>                    
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How can you guarantee this should work for other columns (48, 72, etc). Furthermore what if the entities does not contain one of the `i+24` indexes?

Comment: I don't :) I just answer the question, supposing that the OP controls precisely what is in `$entities`. For indexes>47, I have no idea what to do with them! And if there is less than 48 entities, I can't guess if it is a "lundi" or a "mardi" one which is missing. I don't know the background of the OP question, but I guess I would personnaly have done it in a complete different way...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to pass the array of objects of your entity through controller to the twig file

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('PublishDemandsBundle:Appointement')->findBy(array('therapist'=>$user));
return $this->render('PublishDemandsBundle:Default:myTemplateName.html.twig', array(
    'entities' => $entities
));
```

Now in your twig file you can apply following logic:

```
<table width="80%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr style=" width:100%;">
        <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>lun</th>
        <th>mardi</th>
        <th>mercredi</th>
        <th>jeudi</th>
        <th>vendredi</th>
        <th>Samedi</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for entity in entities if loop.index < 24 %}
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            {% for i in 1..6 %}
            <td>
               {% if entities[loop.parent.loop.index0 + (loop.index0 * 24)] is defined %}
               <a href="">{{ entities[loop.parent.loop.index0 + (loop.index0 * 24)].id }}</a>
               {% endif %}
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```